# частичное игнорирование DataGrid.HeadersVisibility = Column

Tags: wpf

Есть стиль

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
  <!-- бла бла бла -->
  <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column"/>
  <!-- бла бла бла -->
</Style>
```

Все отлично, но иногда при прокрутке длинного `DataGrid` появляются `RowHeader` и вся строка сдвигается немного вправо. Как избежать этого эффекта?

PS: Эффект может появится сразу, а может не беспокоить неделями. 
Среда VS 2012 pro (.net 4.5.51209)

Comment: Ну, если это баг, то как бы баг. Какую версию WPF используете?

Comment: .Net 4.5.51209, MVS(Pro)2012

Comment: А нет поблизости более новой студии, чтобы перепроверить на ней?

Comment: Завтра узнаю о наличии лицензии

Comment: @all Может, кто-нибудь со свежей студией может перепроверить?

Comment: Да в том то и дело что это может вообше не появиться в течении дня :(

Comment: Ого, это хуже. Внесите это в вопрос, может быть важно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015: под Windows 7 баг не проявляется, а вот под Windows XP - вовсю.

Решается установкой RowHeaderWidth=0, взято из
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683631/wpf-datagrid-row-header-visibility-error

Comment: в 7-ке за год появился баг 2 раза. Думаю это вариант решения...